# Why is PyCharm not finding Modules that Visual Studio does?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I have a line in my code at the top of a python file before the class def:

```
import DataManagement.game_start_manager as game_start_manager_
```

I write my Python in Visual Studio 2019 because by trade I'm a C# developer so I had it already.
I was looking at moving to PyCharm for Python coding so as to be more alligned with the Python world.

The code above works fine in Visual Studion, however, in PyCharm I am being told that there is "No Module" named DataManagement.

In my folder structure DataManagement is the name of a folder and game_start_manager is the name of a file: game_start_manager.py which contains a class: GameStartManager.

The code shown above is in a separate folder (Main/start_up.py) at the same level:

i.e.

- Main

  - start_up.py
- DataManagement

  - game_start_manager.py

Visual Studio seems to treat folders and (I think) files as Modules whereas PyCharm does not?

My concern is that I am misunderstanding a fundemental idea surrounding Modules in Python and that is leading to my problem.

What is the cause of the mismatch between my code evaluation in VS 2019 and PyCharm?